# Sinatra ActiveRecord Error by migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I get the same error always, when i try to use command `rake db:migrate`, if table already exists

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Psych::Coder
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'

set :database, "sqlite3:barbershop.db"

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Barber < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My gem file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "sqlite3"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "sinatra-contrib"

group :development do
    gem "tux"
end
```

My migration file:

http://paste2.org/gVA1vj3g

And my Rakefile :

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

I don't know what is Psych, i don't use this gem. I tryed to require this gem, but this did'nt help. How can i fix it?

Comment: What's your Ruby version?

Comment: @p4sh4 ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @p4sh4 if i remove folder with migrations and create it again, than command rake db:migrate works but only at first time

Comment: It's kind of a weird issue, most likely a problem with your Ruby installation. Can you try running `gem cleanup' and see if that helps. Also, try calling rake with `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: @p4sh4 i tryed, but error is still here

Comment: @p4sh4 when i try to run it with bundle exec rake db:migrate there is no effect, no error, nothing

Comment: @p4sh4 i mean, i have no output

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22397 and https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml/issues/72

Comment: @p4sh4 i fixed it! I used gem uninstall psych. Thank you!